How can i move this car (along with wheels) through X axis when clicking forward and backward button
This is my code :
  <body>
    <div class="backgroundImg">
      <!-- <video autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> -->
      <img src="Scene.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="forward"></button>
      <button class="backward"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="road"></div>
    <div class="wholecar">
      <div class="car"></div>
      <div class="wheel1">
        <img src="wheel1.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="wheel2">
        <img src="wheel2.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

This is my CSS code:
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* CAR */

.car {
  height: 309px;
  width: 552px;
  background-image: url(carfinal.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 408px;
  top: 585px;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: CarMoves 1.5s linear infinite;
}

/* FRONT WHEEL */

.wheel1 img {
  width: 122px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 770px;
  left: 805px;
  animation: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
.wheel1 img.play-forward {
  animation: WheelRotate 0.5s linear infinite;
}
.wheel1 img.play-backward {
  animation: WheelRotate 0.5s linear infinite reverse;
}

/* BACK WHEEL */

.wheel2 img {
  width: 122px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 770px;
  left: 492px;
  animation: none;
  z-index: 3;
}
.wheel2 img.play-forward {
  animation: WheelRotate 0.5s linear infinite;
}
.wheel2 img.play-backward {
  animation: WheelRotate 0.5s linear infinite reverse;
}

/* CAR BODY WITH WHEELS */

/* .wholecar .car{
  z-index: 4;
  left:100px
}
.wholecar .wheel1 img{
  left: 500px;
}
.wholecar .wheel2 img{
  left: 185px;
} */

/* BUTTONS */

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.forward {
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url(right.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 90px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 105vh;
}
.backward {
  height: 80px;
  width: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid red;
  background-image: url(left.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 80vh;
}

/* ANIMATIONS */

@keyframes WheelRotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


I have an HTML file with a structure that includes a background image or video, buttons for moving forward and backward, a road element, a car, and two wheels. The car and wheels have their own CSS styling and animations.
In my JavaScript code, I've added event listeners to the forward and backward buttons. When these buttons are clicked, corresponding CSS classes are toggled on the road, background image, and wheels to initiate animations.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the wheels aren't moving along with the car when it moves forward or backward.
To address this, I've attempted to use the translate property on the .wholecar class to move the entire car along with its wheels. However, this approach didn't work as expected.
I'm seeking assistance in resolving this issue so that when the forward or backward buttons are clicked, not only the background and road animate, but the car and its wheels move accordingly to create a realistic driving animation.

Your wrapping wholeCar has no position, so moving it all won't affect the absolutely positioned elements within. You should make the wheels and car relative to the wholeCar class, and then move the whole thing as one block.

"For the whole project file view it on my github" - no, please do not refer us to outside platforms, to be able to reproduce your problem. A proper [mre] of your issue, belongs directly into your question.

Stacking up different linear transformation might not preserve colinearity (keeping objects out of the line) like the combination of rotation and translation in your case.
I believe the easiest solution would be dynamically changing left and top properties in your javascript file instead of translating.

I want to change the left and right of the wholebody which includes my cars body and wheels but how can i do that in js

You could translate the wrapper without affecting internal coordinates. When animating, it's better to not use top and left as they aren't really good for performance and it is generally regarded as a nono.

I did it using setInterval() and clearInterval()
function moveCar() {
const step = 2;
const currentLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(car).left);
const newLeft = currentLeft + moveDirection * step;
car.style.left = newLeft + "px";
but i had to write 3 different functions for wheel1,wheel2 and car.
but moving left gradually solved my problem. :)

I did it using setInterval() and clearInterval()


function moveCar() { 
const step = 2; 
const currentLeft = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(car).left); 
const newLeft = currentLeft + moveDirection * step; 
car.style.left = newLeft + "px";
} 



but i had to write 3 different functions for wheel1,wheel2 and car. but moving left gradually solved my problem. :)
